# Saving Time in Unity using C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

So I've got two classes . First class is a class in which there is a timer .

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class helpmetimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;
    private bool finnished = false;

    void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (finnished)
            return;
        float t = Time.time - startTime;
        string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f0");
        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    public void Finnish()
    {
        finnished = true;
        timerText.color = Color.yellow;
    }
}
```

the second is class is the one which I use to save data i.e name, score and timerText using JSON. I have no problems saving name which is a string and score which is an integer . Problem comes when I try to save the timerText.

Second class which I've used for initialization is ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class helperclass
{
    public string name;
    public int score;
    //dunno what is to be used for timer.
}
```

and finally the 3rd class that is used to save data.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class savegameformaterial1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    static readonly string SAVE_FILE = "new.json";

    void Start()
    {
        helperclass data = new helperclass() { name = "ravi", score =0 };
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        Debug.Log(json);
        string filename = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, SAVE_FILE);
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.Delete(filename);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
        Debug.Log("Player saved to" + filename);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        helperclass data = new helperclass() { name = "billiejoe", score = score4.scoreValue };
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        Debug.Log(json);
        string filename = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, SAVE_FILE);
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            File.Delete(filename);
        }
        File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
        Debug.Log("Player saved to" + filename);
    }
}
```

If I can save timerText or time in the same manner I am able to save name and score then my task would be completed. Any help will be appreciated . I tried to convert timerText to string and then access it but its not working . Then I tried converting it to a char  array but still no luck . 
This is a part of the game in which I have to pick a certain object and place it at a certain position . if there is a failed attempt that is stored in the variable text . Name is written beforehand and the time taken for the process is named timertext .

Comment: Can you state how you tried this?  "tried to convert timerText to string and then access it but its not working ".Because timerText.text is a string and I think it can be saved .

Comment: timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;//this is the final line in timer class         i added  timerText.ToString in the end . Is this how we convert text to string ?

Comment: 1.Do not save file *every frame*. That's really awful. Do that in the `OnApplicationPause` function once the program is about to exit. 2.The duplicate has a function to serialize and save data at once. If you don't want to use the wrapper, the code in it should get you started on how to make your own.

Comment: You are supposed to load the saved data in the `Start` or `Awake` function then save it in the `OnApplicationPause` function

Answer (score 0):

```
      public class helperclass
        {
            public string name;
            public int score;
            public string time; //dunno what is to be used for timer.
        }
        void Start()
            {
 GameObject timerobject= GameObject.Find("timerobject");
            helpmetimer  htimer= timerobject.GetComponent<helpmetimer>();

                helperclass data = new helperclass() { name = "ravi", score =0 ,time=htimer.timerText.text };

            ...
}
```

timerobject is the gameobject on which the helpmetimer is attached.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what do those 3 dots at the end mean ?

Comment: Your code continued

Comment: your fix worked man ! thank you so much.